# How to check if any of the rectangle points fall within a trapezoids ROI - OpenCV & C++

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I want to filter out whether my detected rectangle boxes are falling in a trapezoids ROI or not. Any idea how to do it in opencv c++.
For example: `std::vector<cv::Rect> detectedBoxes = ({xtop, yleft, xbottom, yright});`
Now i want to check whether any of the rectangle box points fall in trapezoids ROI: `std::vector<cv::Vec2f>& polypts`.
The polypts has Upper left & right corner coordinate and Down left & right corner coordinate.

Comment: "Trapezoids"? I am confused. Why do you have a vector of 2d points? Generally, if your polygon is convex then it is an easy test, otherwise it is quite complex.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: [OpenCV - ROI for trapezoid](https://answers.opencv.org/question/43805/roi-for-trapezoid/)

Comment: Sounds like you want to [test whether a point is inside a polygon](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722)...

Comment: @DanMasek he infact needs 4 times "line inside polygon"  which is different if the polygon is not convex. Furthermore, there are faster tests for "point inside convex polygon". His trapezoids should be convex but he has some vector of 2d points `polypts`. Are they even trapezoids?

Comment: @ALX23z yes 2d points because it contains (x,y) coordinates for both Upper left & right points coordinate and Down left & right points coordinate.

Comment: @TedLyngmo your mentioned link make sense but its a bit computational expensive. I am using this link solution, it works well but again it very complex. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/